# How can I add more permissions/ events in my app?

Tags: android, ios, api, sdk, neura

I am trying to use the Neura SDK in my application. I was able to run the authentication flow, but now I want to add more permissions to it.

Answer (score 2):

Its very easy to add more permissions in your application in Neura.

Go to [My Apps](https://dev.theneura.com/console/apps) on the Neura Devsite, click on the specific application you want to add permissions into.

Go to option no 5, Permissions, and toggle the permissions which you want to add/remove. 
[Refer to this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaiIk.png)

Note: Be sure to provide the description, for why you need those permissions.